# Bootstrap grid system inside table

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<div class="table-responsive">
   <table class="table">
      <thead>
         Head
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td>
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-lg-6">Item 1.0</div>
               <div class="col-lg-6">Item 1.1</div>
            </div>
            </td>
            <td>
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-lg-6">Item 2.0</div>
               <div class="col-lg-6">Item 2.1</div>
            </div>   
         </td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

This code creates a table where all items are in the same line. I have searched the `css` file but there is nowhere defined `inline` or `inline-block`, so I guess this is normal bootstrap behavior. What I am trying to achieve is to show items with prefix `1` one after another and same for items with prefix `2`, but I want them all in same row. I have tried using `<ul>` with `<li>` elements, but they are also showed in the same line for some reason.
My table should contain only two columns and one header above them all. This is what I get now:
[image]

Comment: year thead is invalid. you are missing tr's and th/td's

Comment: Yes, you are right, but that's not causing my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is due to column classes - **col-lg-6** which makes divs use equal width of parent td, use class **col-lg-12** to use complete td width, please check the css of these classes below

```
.col-lg-12 {
    width: 100%;
}

.col-lg-12 {
    width: 50%;
}
```

Run below code

```html
favorite
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="table-responsive">
   <table class="table">
      <thead>
         Head
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td>
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-lg-12">Item 1.0</div>
               <div class="col-lg-12">Item 1.1</div>
            </div>
            </td>
            <td>
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-lg-12">Item 2.0</div>
               <div class="col-lg-12">Item 2.1</div>
            </div>   
         </td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

codepen for reference - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/xybpMm

Comment: Not me. I have found what is causing the problem, it's `float: left`. Is there a way  to overwrite that rule?

Comment: Here, I gave you upwote, now it's on `0`

Comment: did you get chance to check my code above , are you expecting similar output?

Comment: Yeah, that's it. Thanks. But can you just give me the answer on my last question?

Comment: single row issue is due to class- col-lg-6

Comment: class name  which you are trying to overwrite , i will update my codepen

Comment: .className { float:right } would overwrite and if that is not working use float:right !important but use important as last option , as it would everywhere you using that class name

Comment: no reason for upvote. Collaboration and help the only reason. This help me too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand yet why you need to use bootstrap grid system inside the table when the td's are designed to work like that. You're also using col-lg-6 which is equivalent to 2 td's inside 1 tr since there is no collapse (lg).

You'll have a similar output if you use this code;

```html
<h6>Default:</h6>
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan='2'>
          Head
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Item 1.0
        </td>
        <td>
          Item 1.1
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Item 2.0
        </td>
        <td>
          Item 2.1
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<br>
<h6>Two Columns Only:</h6>
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan='4'>
          Head
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Item 1.0
        </td>
        <td>
          Item 1.1
        </td>
        <td>
          Item 2.0
        </td>
        <td>
          Item 2.1
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: As you can see, your snippet is not working as I need it to. I need in same row items 1.0 and 1.1 one UNDER another and in column next to them same for items 2.0 and 2.1.
Your snippet shows all of them in same row, not one Under another.